# Applying different multiplier to an integer depending on threshold

Tags: arrays, ruby, hash

I'm having to build a program which calculates the Annual cost of minutes used for phone providers and it depends on different rates.

As an example one  phone operator may have the following rates:

```
  "rates":           [
      {"price": 15.5, "threshold": 150},
      {"price": 12.3, "threshold": 100},
      {"price": 8}
    ],
```

operators can have multiple tariffs with the last tariff always having no threshold.

so in the example above the first 150 minutes will be charged at 15.5p per minute, the next 100mins will be charged at 12.3p per minute and all subsequent minutes will be charged at 8p.

Therefore if:

```
AnnualUsage = 1000
```

the total cost would be 95.55.

I'm struggling to visualise a method which would accommodate for the multiple tariffs an operator could have and multiplying a value by a different price depending on threshold.

Please Help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just another option, I think it's self explanatory:

```
rates =  [
      {price: 15.5, threshold: 150},
      {price: 12.3, threshold: 100},
      {price: 8}
    ]

annual_usage = 1000

res = rates.each_with_object([]) do |h, ary|
  if h.has_key?(:threshold) && annual_usage > h[:threshold]
    annual_usage -= h[:threshold]
    ary << h[:threshold] * h[:price]/100
  else
    ary << annual_usage * h[:price]/100
  end
end

res #=> [23.25, 12.3, 60]
res.sum #=> 95.55
```

Take a look to [Enumerable#each_with_object](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.0.preview3/Enumerable.html#method-i-each_with_object).

Comment: This looks better than my answer, especially because you are returning the amount at each tier. well done.

Answer (score 2):

```
def tot_cost(rate_tbl, minutes)
  rate_tbl.reduce(0) do |tot,h|
    mins = [minutes, h[:threshold] || Float::INFINITY].min
    minutes -= mins
    tot + h[:price] * mins
  end
end
```

```
rate_tbl = [
  { price: 15.5, threshold: 150},
  { price: 12.3, threshold: 100 },
  { price: 8 }
]
```

```
tot_cost(rate_tbl, 130) #=> 2015.0 (130*15.5)
tot_cost(rate_tbl, 225) #=> 3247.5 (150*15.5 + (225-150)*12.3)
tot_cost(rate_tbl, 300) #=> 3955.0 (150*15.5 + 100*12.3 + (300-250)*8)
```

If desired, `h[:threshold] || Float::INFINITY` can be replaced by

```
h.fetch(:threshold, Float::INFINITY)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
RATES = [
  {price: 15.5, threshold: 150},
  {price: 12.3, threshold: 100},
  {price: 8}
]

def total_cost(annual_usage)
  rate_idx = 0
  idx_in_threshold = 1

  1.upto(annual_usage).reduce(0) do |memo, i|
    threshold = RATES[rate_idx][:threshold]
    if threshold && (idx_in_threshold > RATES[rate_idx][:threshold])
      idx_in_threshold = 1
      rate_idx += 1
    end
    idx_in_threshold += 1
    memo + RATES[rate_idx][:price]
  end
end

puts total_cost(1000).to_i
# => 9555
```

The key concepts:

- using an enumerable method such as [reduce](https://apidock.com/ruby/Enumerable/reduce) to incrementally build the solution. You could alternatively use `each` but `reduce` is more idiomatic.
- tracking progress through the rates list through the `rate_idx` and `idx_in_threshold` variables. These give you all the information you need to determine whether you should advance to the next tier.

Also, avoid writing your hash keys like `"price": 15.5` - just remove the quotations, it's more idiomatic.

Comment: Thanks Max, this was very helpful! I hadn't considered reduce

Answer (score 1):

With object-oriented approach you can remove explicit `if ..else` statements and maybe make code more self explanatory.

```
class Total
  attr_reader :price

  def initialize(usage)
    @usage = usage
    @billed_usage = 0
    @price = 0
  end

  def apply(rate)
    applicable_usage = [@usage - @billed_usage, 0].max
    usage_to_apply = [applicable_usage, rate.fetch(:threshold, applicable_usage)].min

    @price += usage_to_apply * rate[:price]
    @billed_usage += usage_to_apply
  end
end
```

Simple usage with `each` method

```
rates =  [
  {:price =>  15.5, :threshold => 150},
  {:price => 12.3, :threshold => 100},
  {:price => 8}
]

total = Total.new(1000)
rates.each { |rate| total.apply(rate) }

puts "Total: #{total.price}" # Total: 9555.0 (95.55)
```

Comment: Nice use of `Hash#fetch`.